# Jhipster swagger ui - permissions

Tags: jhipster

In Jhipster, what is the easiest way to allow a user with role ROLE_USE to access the embedded swagger-ui (and perhaps also allow them to use the usual authorize button to automatically add their access token to all requests)

Comment: I just added this to SecurityConfiguration.java. And although it exposes some management api documentation they are not callable by anyone other than an admin user. I just need to tell user to go to the 'http://localhost:8080/admin/docs' url to see the swagger.  ````.pathMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .pathMatchers("/api/admin/docs").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)````

Comment: Why putting code in comments? Please edit your question, it'll be more readable

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to open up this route to regular users, in my opinion the best approach is to move it out of `/admin`.

First open `admin-routing.module.ts` and remove the following lines:

```js
      {
        path: 'docs',
        loadChildren: () => import('./docs/docs.module').then(m => m.DocsModule),
      },
```

Now edit `app-routing.module.ts` and add the `/docs` route:

```js
// ...
        },
        {
          path: 'login',
          loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule),
        },
        {
          path: 'docs',
          data: {
            authorities: [Authority.ADMIN, Authority.USER],
          },
          canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
          loadChildren: () => import('./admin/docs/docs.module').then(m => m.DocsModule),
        },
        ...LAYOUT_ROUTES,
      ],
      { enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
// ...
```

Change the old `routerLink` for the docs menu entry in your `navbar.component.html`:

```html
          <li *ngIf="openAPIEnabled">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="docs" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="collapseNavbar()">
              <fa-icon icon="book" [fixedWidth]="true"></fa-icon>
              <span>API</span>
            </a>
          </li>
```

Now if you access `localhost:8080/docs` you should be able to use the *swagger-ui* as a regular user.

This is just the minimal amount of changes you require, some things to keep in mind:

- You could move the folder `\src\main\webapp\app\admin\docs` into `\src\main\webapp\app\docs`, just to keep things tidy and coherent. If you do this remember to update the reference in your `app-routing.module.ts`.
- You should add a new menu entry in your navbar for regular users to navigate into swagger, this is trivial so I leave it to you.